# How to store GPS coordinates from GPS device (iPhone, Android, WP7) to remote server?

Tags: iphone, android, windows-phone-7, gps

I'm very interested in all these location-aware based devices (all the new phones and other GPS devices) and am wondering how I can "track" a particular GPS device?  For example, say I put this device in my car, is there a way I can harness those coordinates and send them to a server for later viewing?  I can create a UI and map the coordinates accordingly, but not sure how to get the coordinates out of a particular device?

Let's say I have an iPhone/Android/WP7 phone, is there a way I can get those coordinates sent via a web service or so?

Any and all advice will be greatly appreciated!

UPDATE: I don't plan on having a UI on the device.  I just need to "push"/get the coordinates to some server.  With the data stored somewhere, I can then just create a web service and harness them in a browser application.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Are you looking to have an app that harvests the locations and pushes them to the server or something in the background without user interaction?

Comment: Is this for your own personal use or for an app you want to distribute? if the former, have you looked at Google My Tracks on Android?

Comment: Thanks djg for you quick reply.  I have updated my post.  I don't need a UI on the device, just in the background will suffice.

Comment: Thanks Stealth Rabbi for your quick reply.  I have updated my post with more details.  For starters, it just for personal use (to prototype), but ultimately, I would like to distribute it (to enterprises and not for consumer use).

Answer (score 2):

I have a windows app that does this (desktop not phone). A timer fires every x seconds, grabs the location from the GPS and calls a web service that stores the info in a back-end database.

The process should be similar on a phone app. The only problem with windows phone is that it does not currently multi-task so you will not be able to have a hidden process running.

Android should be ok with a background task.

Not sure about iPhone.

Comment: +1, but had to add that multitasking is supposed to be available with the Mango update.

Comment: I don't quite get it. What GPS data are you pulling? A local device connected to the desktop?

Comment: My windows app runs on Panasonic toughbooks which have a built in GPS device.